# TSQL query for viewing start/end of all SQL Agent jobs yesterday

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

See this related query: [What's a good tool for visualizing SQL Agent jobs?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/14080/whats-a-good-tool-for-visualizing-sql-agent-jobs)

I'm not after a visual tool however, since I am looking to build my own visualisation.  This is my starting point, but you'll agree it's sorely lacking.

```
select TOP(1000)
       h.run_date, min(h.run_time), j.name, j.description, max(h.run_duration) run_duration
from msdb..sysjobhistory h
join msdb..sysjobs j on j.job_id = h.job_id
group by h.run_date, j.name, j.description, h.instance_id, j.job_id
having max(h.run_duration) > 1000  -- << -- 10 minutes encoded in HHMMSS (digits)
order by h.run_date desc, 2 desc
```

The crux is that there does not seem to be a key to the `sysjobhistory` table to identify it as a particular "instance" of a `sysjob`.  For example, a job that started at 12:30 with 4 steps gets inserted into `sysjobhistory` 4 times with *different* instance_ids (unique).  They all tie to the `sysjob.job_id` value, but that's the schedule, not the invocation of the job.  Is there another table in which I should look?

This is probably fairly simple, since SSMS is able to do it easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to filter where the step_id = 0 which is the job outcome and has the total run duration.

```
SELECT TOP ( 1000 )
        h.run_date ,
        MIN(h.run_time) ,
        j.name ,
        j.description ,
        MAX(h.run_duration) run_duration
FROM    msdb..sysjobhistory h
        JOIN msdb..sysjobs j ON j.job_id = h.job_id
WHERE   step_id = 0
GROUP BY h.run_date ,
        j.name ,
        j.description ,
        h.instance_id ,
        j.job_id
HAVING  MAX(h.run_duration) > 1000  -- << -- 10 minutes encoded in HHMMSS (digits)
ORDER BY h.run_date DESC ,
        2 DESC
```